# Akka http return async response from directive (java)

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I want to have an actor based service which is accessible via http.
I'm new to akka, but after researching I came to the conclusion that using akka http will be the best approach for me.

I'm implementing a server that uses the akka http like so:

```
class MyServer extends AllDirectives {
    private final Http http;
    private final Materializer materializer;
    private final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed> routes;

    private ServerBinding binding;

    MyServer(final ActorSystem system) {
        this.http = Http.get(system);
        this.materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);
        this.routes = this.createRoutes().flow(system, materializer);
    }

    CompletionStage<ServerBinding> start() {
        return this.http
                .bindAndHandle(this.routes, ConnectHttp.toHost("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT), this.materializer)
                .thenApplyAsync(serverBinding -> {
                    this.binding = serverBinding;
                    return serverBinding;
                });
    }

    CompletionStage<BoxedUnit> stop() {
        return this.binding.unbind();
    }

    private Route createRoutes() {
        // create routes 
    }
}
```

In the `createRoutes` method I want to create an hierarchical route tree (or forest) using directives, something like:

```
private Route createRoutes() {
    return pathPrefix("typeOne", () ->
                path(PathMatchers.segment(), id ->
                    get(() -> handleTypeOneGetRequest(id))
                    .orElse(post(() -> handleTypeOnePostRequest(id, requestData)))
                )
            ).orElse(pathPrefix("typeTwo", () ->
                path(PathMatchers.segment(), id ->
                        get(() -> handleTypeTwoGetRequest(id))
                        .orElse(post(() -> handleTypeTwoPostRequest(id, requestData)))
                )
    ));
}
```

When handling requests (`handleTypeOneGetRequest` for example) I'd like to pass a message to the appropriate actor (`TypeOne` for example) and return an async response that will be fulfilled when a response message returns from the actor.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to access the `RequestContext` when handling the directives.

My questions are:

- How to I obtain the `RequestContext` in the directive?
- Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure if I got your question right, but as far as I got you, you want to basically let an actor handle your request and then return a result. I usually use Scala so please don't mind my possible Syntax Errors in your Java8 code ;)

I usually use the akka ask pattern to retrieve a future of the response object sent by the actor and then use the onSuccess directive to extract the actual value out of the future. 
Since actor responses are by default untyped you need to check if it actual is what you expected and then you can complete your request with the value. (You probably also need to cast the object, so your response marshallers work).

```
Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, "seconds"));    

private Route createRoutes() {
    return pathPrefix("typeOne", () ->
                path(PathMatchers.segment(), id ->
                    get(() -> 
                            onSuccess(() -> Patterns.ask(actor, id, timeout),
                                      extraction -> if (extraction instanceof WhatEverYouExpect) complete(extraction)
                                     )
                        )
    ));
}
```

Ask Pattern: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html

onSuccess Directive: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onSuccess.html

**EDIT**

You should have a look at the extract* directives:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/java/http/routing-dsl/directives/alphabetically.html

Specifically extract:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/java/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/extract.html#extract-java

```
final Route route = extract(
  ctx -> ctx.getRequest().getUri().toString().length() // extract anything you need and pack into your object
  len -> //use your object
);
```

I suppose that's what you need.

---

#### Edit (by the OP)

Here's a complete solution to the problem, including the `HttpContext`, the usage of an `Actor` for an async response and how to make it work in java:

```
pathPrefix("typeOne", () ->
    path(PathMatchers.segment(), segment ->
        get(() ->
            extract(
                context -> context,
                context -> onSuccess(() -> 
                    FutureConverters.toJava(Patterns.ask(ACTOR_REF, MESSAGE, TIMEOUT)),
                    extraction -> complete(DO_SOMETHING_WITH(segment, context, extraction))
                ).orElse(...)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers part of my question (how to return an async response and asking the actor to process the request). The other part is how to gain access to the `RequestContext` in the directives, that is, when passing a message to the actor I want that message to contain info (post/get data, headers, etc) from the `RequestContext`, but I haven't found a way to get that.

Comment: Sorry, I thought with another approach, you wouldn't need the RequestContext. Adapted my answer accordingly

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that!  I'll play around with it the next couple of days, I might have more questions regarding this when I'll use it. I'll mark the answer as right then. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was mostly right, I just had to combine the two issues (using and actor and getting the `RequestContext`) and also needed to convert from scala `Future` to java `CompletionStage`. I edited your answer and added the complete solution for the benefit of future readers. Thanks again!